# Multiple scopes results in failed authorization

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I've been trying to get my authorization working using the Authorization Code Flow with the example from Spotipy API, as seen below.

```
import sys
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util

scope = 'user-library-read playlist-read-private' # or else

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    username = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print("Usage: %s username" % (sys.argv[0],))
    sys.exit()

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope)

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    results = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
    for item in results['items']:
        track = item['track']
        print(track['name'] + ' - ' + track['artists'][0]['name'])
else:
    print("Can't get token for", username)
```

I managed to get it working just fine with the scope being `'user-library-read'`, but upon changing the scope or adding another, I get the request to re-authenticate. I copy the redirect URL in the editor as usual and get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Joel/PycharmProjects/untitled1/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope)
  File "C:\Users\Joel\.virtualenvs\untitled1-1cFj5f_i\lib\site-packages\spotipy\util.py", line 86, in prompt_for_user_token
    token_info = sp_oauth.get_access_token(code)
  File "C:\Users\Joel\.virtualenvs\untitled1-1cFj5f_i\lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py", line 217, in get_access_token
    raise SpotifyOauthError(response.reason)
spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: Bad Request
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? I'm stumped, since it works just fine with that one specific scope (and doesn't require me to authorize since I've already done it), but with others I get this.

Also, when running the code in my terminal, it requires me to authorize as well, only I get the following error in the browser: `INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI`

Comment: Your code works for me - I would try again in case the Spotify Accounts API was down and double check your redirect URI is configured correctly.